# Uploading from the Android Camera to Python AppEngine (webapp)

Tags: python, android, google-app-engine, httpclient, android-camera

I have two byte[] arrays from the Android Camera Service. I want to POST them, and a few parameters to my AppEngine server, running the python webapp framework.

**PROBLEM**: I keep getting empty HTTP request arguments on the server side.

My main approach has been Apache HttpClient:

1) Android 2.x doesn't include the MultiPartEntity class, needed for multipart w/ binaries. So I've added httpmime-4.0.1.jar and apache-mime4j-0.6.1.jar to the build path.

2) Android side, I'm doing the POST like this:

```
public String post(String URI, byte[] jpeg, String description) {
    // Setup MultiPartEntity
    MultipartEntity args = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    args.addPart("mydescription", new StringBody(description));

    // Now add the file
    InputStream s1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(jpeg);
    args.addPart("myfile", new InputStreamBody(s1, "image/jpeg", "1.jpeg"));

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // HTTP 1.1 is much faster with HttpClient, same issues w/o it  
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(URI);
    httpost.setEntity(args);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);

    // blah blah blah, process response
}
```

3) Python AppEngine side, my handler looks like:

```
class UploadHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self, request):
        logging.info(self.request.arguments())
        logging.info(self.request.POST)
```

4) The arguments are empty -> empty arrays are printed to the log. The lower-level `self.request._request__body()` from webob is also empty. bad sign!

5) **If I don't add the InputStreamBody to the MultipartEntity (only StringBody args) everything works fine, and the mydescription argument shows up.**

6) I setup a PHP server and tried posting: **the POST works with PHP!**

7) Something about the format HttpClient is sending causes webapp/webob/wsgi/cgi.FieldStorage or something problems. I can't figure out where its breaking.

8) I've also tried writing raw http multipart/form according to RFC 2388 using URLConnection, with similar results. What RFC is webapp/webob/wsgi/whatever following?

Thanks all!

This is my first major stackoverflow question, hope I've formatted everything right ;-)

Comment: what do you get using `self.request.get("myfile")` ?

Comment: The snippet you're showing for the server end can't be right: The code isn't inside the post() method, as it should be. Can you please include the _actual_ code you're using?

Comment: Snipped out a couple utility functions and got the def post too, thanks for the catch, just tested w/o them there, same effect

Comment: @systempuntoout: '', empty string